# golang mongodb returning empty object when record exists

Tags: go

It seems that the MongoDB driver is not correctly deserializing a valid database entry."
[mongodb database view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMwcO.png)

```
loginRequest := new(User.LoginRequest)

if err := ctx.Bind(loginRequest); err != nil {
    return ctx.JSON(echo.ErrBadRequest.Code, err)
}

user := u.DB.GetByQuery(bson.M{"username": loginRequest.Username})

if user.IsBanned {
    return ctx.JSON(echo.ErrForbidden.Code, helperutils.ErrBannedUser(loginRequest.Username))

} else if !helperutils.ComparePassword(user.HashedPassword, loginRequest.Password) {
    return ctx.JSON(echo.ErrForbidden.Code, helperutils.FAILED_LOGIN)
}

func (m *Mongodb) GetByQuery(query bson.M, destination interface{}) error {
if !m.Exists(query) {
    return utils.ErrNoMatchingDocuments(query)
}
return m.col.FindOne(context.TODO(), query).Decode(&destination)
```

}

I've looked through a debugger, tried different queries, and looked at my connection string, which is valid. I've verified that I'm using the right collection and database.

Comment: Please [don't paste images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11810946); paste as text and format.

Comment: Is the "GetByQuery" method defined at the bottom the same called on approximately line 5 of the shared code and assigned to user? If so, it should not be assigned to "user", it returns and error object which should be handled.

Comment: i made a mistake implementing my interface but i changed it and even if no error is thrown it still returns an empty object im really not sure where to go from here all my fields are exported and have the correct field tags

Comment: You say the fields are exported and have the correct tags. Can you show that piece in the code sample above. There are missing pieces that we cannot see.